# How to restrict arraylist to add up to 12 elements only

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to restrict the arraylist to add upto 12 elements only.I am using this code to do that operation:

```
if(arr.size()<=12){
  //some code 
  arr.add("string value");
}
```

But it is not working it adds only 7 elements.Can anyone help me.

Comment: We can not help you just with that code.. The fragment you put here is correct..

Comment: @adalPaRi but it adds only 7 elements

Comment: post some more code.How you are changing items in your list.

Comment: @Adarsh, no, in the code you've put. If the array has 12 elements or less, then new element is added. The problem shoud be in other part.

Comment: @Adarsh make sure that Arraylist size is Zero before start to perform the addition in ArrayList

Comment: @Vishwa ok let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
int j = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(arrayList.size() <12) {
                arrayList.add("String " + String.valueOf(j));
                j++;
                Log.e("TAG", "onClick: Size: "+ arrayList.size());
            }
        }
    });
}1;
```

Comment: Great, enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Extend ArrayList and overwrite the add method to include your logic.